# Are there any restrictions to java handling unicode user area?

Tags: java, unicode, fonts

I have a custom font with many glyphs in the private use area. When i do `drawString("\ue21f",…);`, nothing is printed, but the char *is* at this codepoint. If i print a simple `A` i get the correct A from my font. Are there any restrictions to unicode user code area in Java…?